# Hibernate refresh only dirty entities

Tags: hibernate, dirty-data

I have a table filled with nearly 50 datas. Some part of code sometimes changes these datas by jdbc call. At database side these datas are being changed by jdbc call while I need to show these changed datas on screen by hibernate load. I used hibernate's refreshEntity for all datas that have changed by jdbc but it run slow.Also I don't want to call refreshEntity for all datas. How I detect only dirty entities to call refreshEntity?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot since you changed data with JDBC, hibernate **cannot**, or any other JPA provider, see the difference in his **managed entities**.

You have changed data outside of its scope.

You would have to make your OWN mechanism sadly.